# How to speed up monte carlo simulation in python

Tags: performance, python-3.x, cython

I have written a poker simulator that calculates the probability to win in texas holdem by running a simulation of games (i.e. monte carlo simulation). Currently it runs around 10000 simulations in 10 seconds which in general is good enough. However, there are apps on the iPhone that are running around 100x faster. I'm wondering whether there's anything I can do to speed up the program significantly. I have already replaced strings with lists and found many ways to speed up the program by around 2-3 times. But what can I do to possibly speed it up 50x-100x? I checked with a profiler but couldn't find any significant bottleneck. I also complied it to cython (without making any changes) but that had no effect on speed either. Any suggestions are appreciated. The full listing is below:

```
__author__ = 'Nicolas Dickreuter'
import time
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

class MonteCarlo(object):

    def EvalBestHand(self, hands):
        scores = [(i, self.score(hand)) for i, hand in enumerate(hands)]
        winner = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0][0]
        return hands[winner],scores[winner][1][-1]

    def score(self, hand):
        crdRanksOriginal = '23456789TJQKA'
        originalSuits='CDHS'
        rcounts = {crdRanksOriginal.find(r): ''.join(hand).count(r) for r, _ in hand}.items()
        score, crdRanks = zip(*sorted((cnt, rank) for rank, cnt in rcounts)[::-1])

        potentialThreeOfAKind = score[0] == 3
        potentialTwoPair = score == (2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        potentialPair = score == (2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        if score[0:2]==(3,2) or score[0:2]==(3,3): # fullhouse (three of a kind and pair, or two three of a kind)
            crdRanks = (crdRanks[0],crdRanks[1])
            score = (3,2)
        elif score[0:4]==(2,2,2,1):
            score=(2,2,1) # three pair are not worth more than two pair
            sortedCrdRanks = sorted(crdRanks,reverse=True) # avoid for example 11,8,6,7
            crdRanks=(sortedCrdRanks[0],sortedCrdRanks[1],sortedCrdRanks[2],sortedCrdRanks[3])

        elif len(score) >= 5:  # high card, flush, straight and straight flush
            # straight
            if 12 in crdRanks:  # adjust if 5 high straight
                crdRanks += (-1,)
            sortedCrdRanks = sorted(crdRanks,reverse=True)  # sort again as if pairs the first rank matches the pair
            for i in range(len(sortedCrdRanks) - 4):
                straight = sortedCrdRanks[i] - sortedCrdRanks[i + 4] == 4
                if straight:
                    crdRanks=(sortedCrdRanks[i],sortedCrdRanks[i+1],sortedCrdRanks[i+2],sortedCrdRanks[i+3],sortedCrdRanks[i+4])
                    break

            # flush
            suits = [s for _, s in hand]
            flush = max(suits.count(s) for s in suits) >= 5
            if flush:
                for flushSuit in originalSuits: # get the suit of the flush
                    if suits.count(flushSuit)>=5:
                        break

                flushHand = [k for k in hand if flushSuit in k]
                rcountsFlush = {crdRanksOriginal.find(r): ''.join(flushHand).count(r) for r, _ in flushHand}.items()
                score, crdRanks = zip(*sorted((cnt, rank) for rank, cnt in rcountsFlush)[::-1])
                crdRanks = tuple(sorted(crdRanks,reverse=True)) # ignore original sorting where pairs had influence

                # check for straight in flush
                if 12 in crdRanks:  # adjust if 5 high straight
                    crdRanks += (-1,)
                for i in range(len(crdRanks) - 4):
                    straight = crdRanks[i] - crdRanks[i + 4] == 4

            # no pair, straight, flush, or straight flush
            score = ([(5,), (2, 1, 2)], [(3, 1, 3), (5,)])[flush][straight]

        if score == (1,) and potentialThreeOfAKind: score = (3, 1)
        elif score == (1,) and potentialTwoPair: score = (2, 2, 1)
        elif score == (1,) and potentialPair: score = (2, 1, 1)

        if score[0]==5:
            handType="StraightFlush"
            #crdRanks=crdRanks[:5] # five card rule makes no difference {:5] would be incorrect
        elif score[0]==4:
            handType="FoufOfAKind"
            crdRanks=crdRanks[:2]
        elif score[0:2]==(3,2):
            handType="FullHouse"
            # crdRanks=crdRanks[:2] # already implmeneted above
        elif score[0:3]==(3,1,3):
            handType="Flush"
            crdRanks=crdRanks[:5] # !! to be verified !!
        elif score[0:3]==(3,1,2):
            handType="Straight"
            crdRanks=crdRanks[:5] # !! to be verified !!
        elif score[0:2]==(3,1):
            handType="ThreeOfAKind"
            crdRanks=crdRanks[:3]
        elif score[0:2]==(2,2):
            handType="TwoPair"
            crdRanks=crdRanks[:3]
        elif score[0]==2:
            handType="Pair"
            crdRanks=crdRanks[:4]
        elif score[0]==1:
            handType="HighCard"
            crdRanks=crdRanks[:5]
        else: raise Exception('Card Type error!')

        return score, crdRanks, handType

    def createCardDeck(self):
        values = "23456789TJQKA"
        suites = "CDHS"
        Deck=[]
        [Deck.append(x+y) for x in values for y in suites]
        return Deck

    def distributeToPlayers(self, Deck, PlayerAmount, PlayerCardList, TableCardsList):
        Players =[]
        CardsOnTable = []
        knownPlayers = 0

        for PlayerCards in PlayerCardList:
            FirstPlayer=[]
            FirstPlayer.append(Deck.pop(Deck.index(PlayerCards[0])))
            FirstPlayer.append(Deck.pop(Deck.index(PlayerCards[1])))
            Players.append(FirstPlayer)

            knownPlayers += 1

        for c in TableCardsList:
            CardsOnTable.append(Deck.pop(Deck.index(c)))  # remove cards that are on the table from the deck

        for n in range(0, PlayerAmount - knownPlayers):
            plr=[]
            plr.append(Deck.pop(np.random.random_integers(0,len(Deck)-1)))
            plr.append(Deck.pop(np.random.random_integers(0,len(Deck)-1)))
            Players.append(plr)

        return Players, Deck

    def distributeToTable(self, Deck, TableCardsList):
        remaningRandoms = 5 - len(TableCardsList)
        for n in range(0, remaningRandoms):
            TableCardsList.append(Deck.pop(np.random.random_integers(0,len(Deck)-1)))

        return TableCardsList

    def RunMonteCarlo(self, originalPlayerCardList, originalTableCardsList, PlayerAmount, gui, maxRuns=6000,maxSecs=5):
        winnerlist = []
        EquityList = []
        winnerCardTypeList=[]
        wins = 0
        runs=0
        timeout_start=time.time()
        for m in range(maxRuns):
            runs+=1
            try:
                if gui.active==True:
                    gui.progress["value"] = int(round(m*100/maxRuns))
            except:
                pass
            Deck = self.createCardDeck()
            PlayerCardList = originalPlayerCardList[:]
            TableCardsList = originalTableCardsList[:]
            Players, Deck = self.distributeToPlayers(Deck, PlayerAmount, PlayerCardList, TableCardsList)
            Deck5Cards = self.distributeToTable(Deck, TableCardsList)
            PlayerFinalCardsWithTableCards = []
            for o in range(0, PlayerAmount):
                PlayerFinalCardsWithTableCards.append(Players[o]+Deck5Cards)

            bestHand,winnerCardType=self.EvalBestHand(PlayerFinalCardsWithTableCards)
            winner = (PlayerFinalCardsWithTableCards.index(bestHand))


            #print (winnerCardType)

            CollusionPlayers = 0
            if winner < CollusionPlayers + 1:
                wins += 1
                winnerCardTypeList.append(winnerCardType)
                # winnerlist.append(winner)
                # self.equity=wins/m
                # if self.equity>0.99: self.equity=0.99
                # EquityList.append(self.equity)
            if time.time()>timeout_start+maxSecs:
                break

        self.equity = wins / runs
        self.winnerCardTypeList = Counter(winnerCardTypeList)
        for key, value in self.winnerCardTypeList.items():
            self.winnerCardTypeList[key] = value / runs

        self.winTypesDict=self.winnerCardTypeList.items()

        # show how the montecarlo converges
        # xaxis=range(500,monteCarloRuns)
        # plt.plot(xaxis,EquityList[499:monteCarloRuns])
        # plt.show()
        return self.equity,self.winTypesDict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Simulation = MonteCarlo()
    mycards=[['AS', 'KS']]
    cardsOnTable = []
    players = 3
    start_time = time.time()
    Simulation.RunMonteCarlo(mycards, cardsOnTable, players, 1, maxRuns=200000, maxSecs=120)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    equity = Simulation.equity # considering draws as wins
    print (equity)
```

Comment: It's probably a runtime issue with your algorithms.

Comment: Yes I have checked them and the outputs match. I have create unit tests to make sure all results are correct. My question is really a technical one. Why is it that my python program is so much slower than other programs doing the same thing? Of course it's possible that they are using lookup tables, but I was wondering if there was any way to speed up the python program that I wrote.

Comment: Those other programs you refer to use compiled code while you use a dynamic interpreted language. Every operation has much more cost in python than in objective C or Java. As such the only way to speed up is to use expressions that are efficiently implemented behind the scrne in compiled C, that more or less means numpy in your case

Comment: As you have a working code and are looking to improve performance, this question is a good candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Perhaps you could try migrating this question there.

Comment: I'm not an expert in any of the relevant areas, but I remember a discussion about poker simulation on the 2+2 forums. A few posters were comparing algorithms iterating through cards to rank hands. Then another person dropped in with a gently mocking comment that there are so few hands that it's obvious to cache all of them and turn hand ranking into a look up problem, not a logic problem. And speed increases dramatically. But other answers below may be more significant, I don't know.

Comment: It’s not the cards that matter, but the card combinations, including the cards on the table. Not possible to cache that.

Comment: Is this not relevant: https://github.com/tangentforks/TwoPlusTwoHandEvaluator    https://github.com/WhatMatters/ray_eval (15M hands/second.)

Comment: "Naive hand evaluators are slow, plain and simple, at least compared to other evaluators. All that sorting, iterating, and conditional branching takes time. While naive evaluators can be built which are fast enough for basic Monte-Carlo style analysis, there's probably never a reason to use them, considering there's so much solid, highly-optimized code available for free."  https://web.archive.org/web/20111103160502/http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/poker-hand-evaluator-roundup#2p2

Comment: The original site from the web archive link is back: https://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/poker-hand-evaluator-roundup/#2p2

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm is too long and complex for any sensible suggestion apart from generic ones. So here you go: vectorise everything you can and work with vectors of data instead of loops, lists, insertions, removals. Montecarlo simulations allow for this quite nicely because all samples are independent.

For example, you want 1 million retries, generate a `numpy` array of random 1 million values in one line. You want to test outcome, place 1 million outcomes into a `numpy` array and test all of them at once against a given condition generating a `numpy` array of booleans.

If you manage to vectorize this you will get tremendous performance increases.

Comment: meaning everything is expressed as a numpy array?

Comment: Yes and that you use array operations wherever possible instead of iterating through them.

Comment: Not the case here, but if you have to generate a large amounts of random numbers (lets say 200) per loop and do 1M sims, will you run into memory issues? What options are there to speed it up in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Inefficient array operations are probably causing most of the slowness. In particular, I see a lot of lines like this:

```
Deck.pop(some_index)
```

Every time you do that, the list has to shift all the elements after that index. You can eliminate this (as well as repeated random functions) by using:

```
from random import shuffle

# Setup
originalDeck = createCardDeck()

# Individual run
Deck = originalDeck[:]
shuffle(Deck) # shuffles in place

# Draw a card from the end so nothing needs to shift
card = Deck.pop()

# Concise and efficient!
```

There are some other things you could do, like change long if-else chains into constant time lookups with a dict or custom class. Right now it checks for a straight flush first down to a high card last for every hand, which seems rather inefficient. I doubt that it would make a big difference though.

Comment: Just tried to replace the random number generators with shuffle as you suggest, but it slows down the whole process by around 25%. I'd assume that shuffle has to rearrange the whole array as well.

Comment: @Nicolas: if `len(Deck)` were large then it would make sense to optimize `Deck.pop()`, `Deck.index()` that are `O(n)` operations e.g., you could have sorted `Deck` and used `bisect` module to find elements in `O(log n)` time (if `n=1000000` then `log n ~ 10` and ~10 steps is *much* better than a million steps) or you could use a `set()` to represent `Deck` then search/removal is `O(1)` (constant time). For small `n` (~10) -- constant factors may matter i.e., more optimal algorithm may be slower for small `n`.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that a shuffle would be more efficient since it doesn't need to reallocate or resize the array more than once. Have you tried numpy.random.shuffle?

Comment: @Nicolas: to be clear: you should call `random.shuffle(Deck)` once per deck (not once per card). After that you only need to call `Deck.pop()` for each card.

Comment: Yes that's what I tried. But for some reason that seemed to be slower. The shuffling appears to take a lot of time.