# How to translate list operations like count, find and zip to numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, find, zip

I have built a poker hand evaluator and would like to transform everything in my code into numpy:

The follwing lines are ranking the hand. It checks how valuable the card is (first number in the tuple which is then split out into crdRank) and how many times each card rank occurs in the hand (second number in the tuple, then split out into score).

What would be a good way to have score and crdRank in a two dimensional numpy array while avoiding non-numpy operations?

```
    crdRanksOriginal = '23456789TJQKA'
    originalSuits='CDHS'
    hand=['9S', '7H', 'KS', 'KH', 'AH', 'AS', 'AC']
    rcounts = {crdRanksOriginal.find(r): ''.join(hand).count(r) for r, _ in hand}.items()
    score, crdRank = zip(*sorted((cnt, rank) for rank, cnt in rcounts)[::-1])

result:
rcounts --> dict_items([(11, 2), (12, 3), (5, 1), (7, 1)])
score --> (3, 2, 1, 1)
crdRank --> (12, 11, 7, 5)
```

Comment: You can hammer a screw, but often a screwdriver is a better option :)

Comment: For small lists `numpy` won't be faster.  But as an exercise, don't copy the code closely. Step back and think in 2d.

Comment: The full code looks like the one listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312405/how-to-speed-up-monte-carlo-simulation-in-python/33313466?noredirect=1#comment54429125_33313466
What's your take, would switching to numpy have a big impact?